# Bounded sequence of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers so that $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L<1$. Then show that for $n$ large enough and for some $C>0$ we have $0<x_n<Cr^n$.

I have been our of practice with these types of questions and couldn't find this in another discussion so thought I would ask (if it is already asked, I would love to see a solution linked).

So what I did was for some $N$ we have $0<\frac{x_{N+1}}{x_N}<L<r$ for some $0<L<r<1$. Then we have $\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\frac{x_{N+1}}{x_{N}}...\frac{x_{N+n}}{x_{N+n-1}}<\frac{x_{N+n}}{x_{N-1}}r^n$... but I'm getting stuck here. Something about this doesn't seem right but I'm not sure what approach to take. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: It's not true that there is necessarily some $N$ such that $x_{N+1}/x_N < L$. However you should be able to show that there exists an $N$ such that $$n > N \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < \frac{L + 1}{2} < 1$$

$\frac{L + 1}{2}$ would be a good choice for $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine $N$ so that for all $n\geq N$ we have $x_{n+1}/x_n < r$ for some $L<r<1$. We can do this because $\lim_n x_{n+1}/x_n = L<1$.

Then $x_{N+1} < x_N r$, and $x_{N+2} < x_{N+1}r < x_N r^2$, and so on. By induction we can prove that $x_{N+m} < x_N r^m$. Now Take $C=x_N$, and we have shown that for all $n \geq N$ we have $x_n < C r^n$.

Comment: Do you mean $r $ instead of $K $?